# Ionic - How to create a new modal with data, from another modal?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, modalviewcontroller

I have a project I'm working on that requires multiple modal views. I'll try to be as clear as possible in explaining this. 
Basically, a user clicks a button and a modal opens. The user can select a user, or can click a button that says manage users - which will take the user to a different modal view, with options to edit the users. 
I am new to ionic, but can anyone explain how I can go about doing this?

Comment: You want to pass parameter through page? See https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavParams/

Comment: No, I want to be able to open a modal from another modal.

Comment: So just do the same way you open the first modal?

Comment: Is that how you do it? You can call openModal() on a button from within a modal? I'm trying that and running into problems.

Comment: @Duannx you were absolutely right. Sorry, my first exposure to ionic began with this project a couple hours ago. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction - I was chasing other solutions when it was that simple.